# Why does everything take so long to open?

Tags: 11.10, performance

Every time I click to open a program or anything, it takes at least 6 seconds to open. Bigger programs take even longer. I right clicked on the desktop and selected "change desktop background" and the thing took like 10 seconds to open. Any reason for this?

Comment: And what are your PC specs.

Comment: Pc specs: AMD Turion(tl-56) 64 x2, 2GB Ram (DDR2) and an ATI HD 3200 (Integrated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be an `/etc/hosts` misconfiguration: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/94048

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure opengl is running by following the instructions in the accepted answer here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27918/getting-opengl-to-work-under-ubuntu

This solved a similar issue for me recently.

Answer (score 0):

A generic answer because the question is so old:

Assuming that this is not caused by some known bug such as the one linked by Tristram Brelstaff in another answer, the reason is probably having too little RAM or bad I/O performance.

A simple test is to do as follows:

- Open a terminal window
- Type `sudo vmstat -SM 1`

Now try to do the thing that takes longer than expected and see what `vmstat` output says while you're waiting for the program to open. Once the program is open you can stop `vmstat` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Depending on `vmstat` values gathered while slow program start was in progress you can deduce following:

- If `swap` `si` or `so` (number of MB swapped in or out per second) values are more than zero, your system is having too little RAM for the workload you have and the system is forced to use hard drive to store some part of the RAM.
- If `cpu` `wa` (total percentage of CPU spent waiting for I/O access to complete) is more than about 100/(number of CPU cores x 2) your system has incorrectly working or too slow hard drive. Check hard drive cabling and verify that the system is using correct protocol to access the drive (e.g. SATA AHCI).
- If `cache`, `free` or `cache` are less than 100 your system probably has too little RAM and performance is bad as a result (memory reserves that may be used by the program that is currently starting).
- If `cpu` `id` (CPU idle time) is less than about 100/(number of CPU cores x 2) your CPU may not be up to task.

If none of the above match your case, then it's probably some software issue caused by some possibly unknown bug.